# Encrypt user passwords when uploading code and decrypt during run-time

Tags: java, encryption, jdbc

Have to begin moving in-house, local machine only Java framework into a private but online repo for staff only, however, the current framework requires a properties class which includes sensitive information (usernames, passwords etc) to login to the database and other technology the framework uses.

As a result, pushing the latest framework will include all of said individuals usernames/passwords, which is a security concern.

I've been asked to "Encrypt the password so when it's uploaded it's hidden" and then "Decrypt the password during runtime, so that information can be used to execute the code, as without the login data, the framework will not work".

While there is much better solutions (ie just don't upload the properties class, rework framework to not need the properties class etc), this is apparently unacceptable as it "works this way".

I'm struggling on the logic of this request, but furthermore how this task could actually be accomplished.
There's a few solutions I pinged about having it in a private notepad on your system only, but again apparently unacceptable.
It "needs to just be within a new Java Class".

Is this request possible, and if so, what sort of approach could I take? So the sensitive information within the properties class is encrypted if someone downloads the framework, but when executed, that information is decrypted and the framework runs. Framework is being uploaded to Bitbucket.

(Not asking for the code, just asking for help working out how this could be achieved, if at all, because it seems to be a very strange request or am I missing something?)

Comment: Can you save data locally? I mean, can you define a key pair that resides on your server locally? If you can, you can just treat the data as a binary chunk, you decrypt them when you download them with the Private Key and encrypt them with the public key when you upload them (i.e. because the password changed). But you cannot upload the keypair, or it would be useless!

Comment: Wait... if it's a password to access a remote DB service, than it's remote concern to crypt the password. The remote password is accessed remotely by the remote server. You can crypt all you want, but, when you access the server you need to specify the password that is stored remotely (hence, if they didn't crypt it, anybody can see it and use it for acces). You can do something only if the password is checked locally.

Comment: Hi Luca, it is indeed a password to access a remote DB service. 
The user data (user-pass, db information) is all in the properties class, which is also contains information to login to your remote desktop, so either it needs to be local or crypted. 
I was thinking this request was not even possible and the real solution and made any sense was to have this properties class only held locally.
Apparently it "needs to be encrypted" and "decrypted" during runtime. I'm not sure it's even possible. They want it all encrypted when the framework is downloaded from Bitbucket and decrypted on run.

Comment: It is possible. Crypt and Decrypt are wrapper for your stream, therefore, you can crypt and decrypt while uploading and downloading the data (and you can compress it too... I strongly suggest to also compress the data, for another layer of security) cliebt side.  The problem is that the password will also be visible server side when you use it to actually access the DB. And the DB must have its internal copy to authenticate the user. Well, those informations should be protected by the service provider already, thus they should not concer you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the snippet to upload your data to the server. `os` must be a valid output stream used for upload.

```
OutputStream os = ... /* your upload stream */
OutputStream gzipos = new GZIPOutputStream(os);
CryptoAlgorithm = "RSA";        
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CryptoAlgorithm);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, PuK);
CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(gzipos, cipher);
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(cos);
dos.write... /* use it as a normal data output stram /*
```

I use DataOutputStream because I used binary data in my implementation. Still, you can also use a normal writer:

```
Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(cos);
```

And, for the download snippet:

```
CryptoAlgorithm = "RSA";
...
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CryptoAlgorithm);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, PK);
CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(is), cipher);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(cis);
```

If you used a writer, obviously you'll need to change the last declaration accordingly:

```
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(cis);
```

Of course you need a Key Pair of

```
PrivateKey PK;
PublicKey Puk;
```

Those two needs to be saved locally (you need to chose how to, just google it and chose how you want to save them, there're several options).

Now, not knowing how well you know RSA, I'll explain a couple of things:

1. **IMPORTANT** before goint to production make sure to have your key pair saved and backupped! Multiple times in different media, if possible. If you lose those keys, your data becomes unreadable, thus **lost forever**!
   Really, protect those keys with evertything you've got!
2. you use the PublicKey to crypt because this way only those who have the private key can uncrypt it, because, normally, you can distribute the PublicKey, and everybody with the public key can decrypt what was crypted with the PriveteKey. This is used for electronic signatures because only the owner of the PrivateKey can write a document that can be opened with the relative PublicKey. On the opposite, everybody can use the PublicKey to cipher a document but only the one with the associated private key can read it. That's why, if you store protected data, you use the public key to cipher and the private to uncipher. Right now it doesn't matter to you, but better be prepared for the future.
3. you can use the algorithm you fancy, but the most used is RSA and it's the one you can find the most informations on.
4. I compress the data before chiphering it not for saving space, but to maximize the randomization of the data, thus making harder to brute-force decipher them. Still, there's a problem: GZip protocol puts GZ before any file compressed with said protocol as signature. You can manually remove that signature before ciphering and add it manually after deciphering, but it become a little more complex to handle. You can bypass the compression part if you want (or find another algorithm to compress/uncompress).